# Is the following phrase correct?

Tags: present-tense

For example, I want to tell a person that I have started waking up at 5 AM from few days.  Can I say

> I am getting up at 5 am.

I read from English grammar book that I have to use a simple present like the statement below.

> I get up at 5 am.

But I started to get up at 5 am only from past few days. What is the exact phrase I should use?

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your question. Can you tell us which grammar book tells you that you must use the simple present? In your case, you could use the _present perfect continuous:_ _"I have been getting up at 5 a.m. for a few days."_ (NOTE: _**for a** few days,_ not _**from** few days._) We hope you will read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you to ask good questions!

Answer (score 1):

**I have been waking up at 5, recently / the last few days / since last week.**

This is how 95%+ of American native speakers would say this.

Comment: British speakers as well.

Answer (score 1):

To denote the pat few days you might say

> I **have been getting up** at 5 am. *(the past few days)*.

but it may not be habitual.

If you will continue to do it

> I **get up** at 5 am.